# Проблема с переменными С#

Tags: c#, файлы

У меня есть два файла. Нужно вытащить переменные из одного в другой. Задала их как глобальные в том файле, где они определяются и заполняются. Но во втором файле, когда их считывает, то они не заполненные, а пустые.
Как можно решить данную проблему?
Код из первого файла:

```
public sealed partial class NewOrder : Page
{
    public string Name1;
    public string Mob;
    public string Adres;
    public string Email;

    public NewOrder()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("...."))
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand(
                "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE mob LIKE N'" + telephone + "'", connection);

            EncodingProvider ppp;
            ppp = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);
            MySqlDataReader reader = createCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Name1 = reader.GetString(1);
                    Mob = reader.GetString(2);
                    Adres = reader.GetString(3);
                    Email = reader.GetString(4);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код из второго файла:

```
public sealed partial class Details : Page
{         
    public Details()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        NewOrder A = new NewOrder();
        name.Text = A.Name1;
        tel.Text = A.Mob;
        adres.Text = A.Adres;
        email.Text = A.Email;                       
    }                   
}
```

Вот что высвечивает:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null.

Comment: Вы пробовали посмотреть это дело под отладчиком и расставлять контрольные точки проверяя значения? Если по сути, ошибка такая - в вашем запросе данных не найдено и потому значениям класса NewOrder ничего не присваивается. Отсюда `name.Text = A.Name1;` аналогичен `name.Text = null;` - ошибка, в TextBox нельзя присвоить `null`. Проверяйте NewOrder класс на правильность запросов и обработку подобных ситуаций.

Comment: Возможно значения из БД вы берете начиная не с того индекса? Т. е. отсчет столбцов БД идет с нуля: 1 - getString(0); Возможно 4го столбца попросту нету? Из какого класса вылетает исключение?

Comment: А в какой строке происходит исключение? И чему равны значения переменных в этой строке? (Вы, надеюсь, запускаете приложение под отладчиком?)

Answer (score -3):

Неверно писать:

```
NewOrder A = new NewOrder();
```

Правильно:

```
NewOrder();
```

Comment: "а....NewOrder();" - у вас  это компилируется? Надо заменить на:  `NewOrder();` Поправте. И добавете - почему так, а не этак.

Comment: синтаксис С++ ?